# Php Mysql Nested Category Subcategories Json Response

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display categories and subcategories as json response using php mysql. I have three level categories. I am running this query but results not coming as expected. please help me to solve this.

I need json response like below

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Electronics",
    "categorieslevelone": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Mobiles",
        "categoriesleveltwo": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Samsung",
            "parent_id": "2"
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Nokia",
            "parent_id": "2"
        }]
    }]
```

My Code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $sql = "select * from category where category_id = 0";
        $q = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute();
        $json_response = array();
        while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $row_array = array();
            $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
            $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
            $row_array['categorieslevelone'] = array();
            $id = $row['id'];
            $sqltwo = "select * from category where category_id = ? ";
            $r = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sqltwo);
            $r->bindParam(1, $id);
            $r->execute();
            while ($data = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $id2 = $data['id'];
                $row_array['categoriesleveltwo'] = array();
                $row_array['categorieslevelone'][] = array(
                    'id' => $data['id'],
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                );
                $sql3 = "select * from category where category_id = ? ";
                $s = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql3);
                $s->bindParam(1, $id2);
                $s->execute();
                while ($list = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $row_array['categoriesleveltwo'][] = array(
                        'id' => $list['id'],
                        'name' => $list['name'],
                    );
                }
            }
            array_push($json_response, $row_array); //push the values in the array
        }
        echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: What does wrong output look like?

Comment: {  
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Electronics",
   "categorieslevelone":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Mobiles"
      },
      {  
         "id":"261",
         "name":"Networking"
      }
   ],
   "categoriesleveltwo":[  
      {  
         "id":"259",
         "name":"Routers"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: above response I am getting

Comment: How do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Hi, just read this, it is simple. http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I need like this but I am not getting as expect

Comment: {  
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Electronics",
   "categorieslevelone":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Mobiles",
         "categoriesleveltwo":[  
            {  
               "id":"259",
               "name":"samsung"
            },
            {  
               "id":"100",
               "name":"nokia"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"261",
         "name":"Networking"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: I dont know about pdo and object oriented structure. But i can solve you using procedural format. Can you convert those code into PDO. Then ill create code for you

Comment: @fairy Thank you for your reply can you give example in procedural format. I will convert into PDo

Comment: ok Im making code for you

Comment: Hi Jack I just posted the code below. Check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting a result like you mentioned above. Chenck this out. You have to convert procedural into Object oriented method.

```
$main_cat = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con,'Select category_id as id,category_name as name from category where parent_id = '.$row['id'].'');
    $sub_cat = array();
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
        $query3 = mysqli_query($con,'Select category_id as id,category_name as name from category where parent_id = '.$row1['id'].'');
        $sub_cat2 = array();
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3))
        {
            array_push($sub_cat2, $row2);   
        }
        $row1['categoriesleveltwo'] = $sub_cat2;
        array_push($sub_cat, $row1);    
    }

    $row['categorieslevelone'] = $sub_cat;
    array_push($main_cat, $row);
}

echo json_encode($main_cat);
?>
```

Hope its will satisfy your requirement

Comment: Thank You So Much Fairy,  Working Fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is already accepted, but I thought it would make nice code kata.

Code below will build tree structure from **adjacency list** that you have in db. There are more ways to maintain tree structures, but there's no easy way - all methods involve maintance/code efficiency trade offs.

I used references to build whole tree in one loop regardless of nested nodes number and order in which rows are fetched (would be much easier when parent node was already fetched, but would need extra attention to changes in db) - this way you could order categories alfabetically with db query.

Since it works for any nesting level all children are stored under `subcategories` key (opposed to `categorieslevelxxx`), but each subtree might be processed the same way.

```
...
$link = [];
$data = [];
while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id     = $row['id'];
    $parent = $row['category_id'];
    unset($row['category_id']);

    empty($link[$id]) or $row += $link[$id];
    isset($link[$parent]['subcategories']) or $link[$parent]['subcategories'] = [];    

    $link[$parent]['subcategories'][] = $row;

    $last_idx  = count($link[$parent]['subcategories']) - 1;
    $link[$id] = & $link[$parent]['subcategories'][$last_idx];
}

$data = $link[1];
unset($link); //tree might be cached here.
```

`$link[1]` at the end means we want category 1 and all it's descendants, but you might take any other node. `$link[0]` would take entire tree when there's more root categories (`category_id = 0` in db points to "virtual" root).

Comment: Thank you for you help shudder